# Is it safe to use setTimeout to bypass module import order issues?

Tags: javascript, redux, settimeout, es6-modules

In my CRA project, I have a `configureStore.ts` file that exports my redux store:

```js
// ...
export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
);
```

and I subscribe to the store manually in `staticIntl.ts`, which is imported hundreds of times throughout the whole project

```js
import { store } from "../configureStore"

class IntlManager  {
  constructor() {
    store.subscribe(this.onStoreChange);
  }
  // ...
}

const manager = new IntlManager()
```

But when I run the project, the `store.subscribe` fails due to

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I am practically certain this is due to import order/availability

I managed to "fix" the issue by pushing the subscribe callback to the end of the task queue via no-delay setTimeout (I know it actually rounds up to couple of MS, but I don't think I really need to mind about that):

```js
constructor() {
  setTimeout(() => store.subscribe(this.onStoreChange));
}
```

Is this safe? I am mostly concerned about three things:

1. is it possible for the subscribe to still fail due to the same reason, even when wrapped in setTimeout ? For example if somehow processing my modules takes a long time
2. Is it possible for a first store update to happen before subscribtion (and thus missing on the subscribe callback call)?
3. Could such update happen as a result of my React app fetching data from the server and dispatching the response?

Are there any other potential pitfalls of my fix/hack?

Also, what other ways could I fix my problem? I'd be especially thankful for a link to a propper guide.

Comment: No it's not. You have no idea how long you should wait. So this might work 50% of the time and the other 50% of the time the person is likely waiting an unnecessarily long amount of time. You need to fix the underlying issue, which appears to be an observable not getting set correctly. So what you should really be asking yourself is why does `createStore` return undefined?

Comment: Perhaps you have a circular dependency in your imports?

Comment: @Liam I strongly disagree with your edit to the question tags. My question has much more to do with the event loop than reactjs. I would understand you deleting the `create-react-app` tag, but not this.

Comment: Well undo the edit then @MichalKurz. I added this tag as I'm presuming `createStore ` is returning some kind of react object. If your subscribing, I'm guessing it' an rxjs observable but not being  react developer I'm not sure if react uses rxjs (like angular does). None of this is to do with the importing of modules. Like I said, *you should really be asking yourself is why does createStore return undefined*

Comment: And thanks for your comment about my solution, @Liam . Are you 100% certain that the first callback registered by setTimeout will not always be executed after executing all of my static, already-queued code? Because It's in no way obvious to me, although certainly plausable.

Comment: @Liam Like I mentioned in my question, `I practically certain this is due to import order/availability`. `createStore` does not return undefined, but is not yet processed by the time I try to subscribe to it.

Comment: I am not sure what the correct term for my issue is

Comment: @Liam By event loop he means how the JS engine functions at runtime, how function calls to imported modules etc. evaluate. Since the setTimeout gives you another "tick". This is how I understood it at least.

Comment: Lets flip that question around @MichalKurz are **you** 100% certain that the first callback registered by setTimeout **will always** be executed after executing all of my static, already-queued code? Because that's what I'm getting at. You can't be certain. Which is why you shouldn't do this. It might work some-of-the-time. Or it might not. Which is why it's not a good solution

Comment: Ok, ley me be clear, this is nothing to do with the ordering of events. The order is undefined (generally) and can't be relied upon. This is why promises, etc. exist. If you need something to run in a particular order then you need to **chain the events yourself** using callbacks, promises or observables, etc. Which is why I keep saying, *you should really be asking yourself is why does createStore return undefined*. Nothing in this question is going to help you. Your real question is the contents of `createStore` that you haven't added

Answer (score 2):

> I practically certain this is due to import order

Yes, this sounds very much like a problem with circular dependencies. Your `configureStore` imports something that depends on `staticIntl`, which in turn imports the store from a module that is not yet evaluated.

Do not use `setTimeout`, fix the underlying problem with your module dependencies.

In particular, I would recommend

- move `const manager = new IntlManager()` into a different file where you clearly control that it is executed after the `createStore(…)` call.
- Use dependency inversion - remove the `store.subscribe(this.onStoreChange)` line from the `IntlManager` constructor and instead write `store.subscribe(manager.onStoreChange)` after you created store.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `IntlManager` is a singleton, and you only need one of these in your app - if this is not true, ignore the following.

Following the classic redux setup https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store my advice is to pass the store as a prop to your main App component. And then create an instance of `IntlManager` by passing the `store` prop to the constructor:

```
const store = configureStore()

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App store={store} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

in `App` component:

```
const { store } = this.props;
const manager = new IntlManager(store);
```

Wether this works depends a bit on how `IntlManager` is actually used by your app. You wrote that it is "imported hundreds of times throughout the whole project". This is ok I think, you might have to rewrite the class a bit so that you can instantiate it right away, but subscribe to the store later, when the store is actually available. I envision something like this:

in `App` component:

```
import manager from '.../IntlManager';
// somewhere in componentDidMount for example:
const { store } = this.props;
manager.subscribeToStore(store);
```